# How is Dijkstra algorithm better tham A* algorithm for finding shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

How is Dijkstra algorithm better tham A* algorithm for finding shortest path?

Comment: Is it? [I thought](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332466/how-does-dijkstras-algorithm-and-a-star-compare) it's just the same as A*, but with heuristics turned off...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not better at finding the shortest path. As long as you have an admissible heuristic for A* it will find the shorted path quicker than Dijkstra's would.

And as Mehrad pointed out in the comments, A* degrades into Dijktras if you give it a heuristic function that returns 0.

The [wikipedia article for A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) has a ton of good information on all of this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the shortest paths from a given source node to **all** nodes in a graph Dijkstra is better than A* since Dijkstra covers the whole graph anyway if you don't stop at a specific target. In contrast to simple Dijkstra A* is a goal-oriented algorithms and therefore needs to know both source and target node. If you wanted to cover the whole graph with N nodes with an A* algorithm you basically have to run the algorithm N times from the source node.

Dijkstra might also be better for finding the shortest paths from a source node to **many** targets of the graph. Depending on the location of the targets (especially distance from the source), number of targets M, size of the graph, quality of the A* heuristic there will be some break-even point where running one Dijkstra is better or less performant than running M times the A* algorithm.

**Edit:** Inspired by Matthew's correct critical comment I rephrase a bit and add remarks:

- Dijkstra is not better in finding the shortest paths to **all** nodes than A*. Correct would be: It's not worse than A*.
- To find the shortest paths to **all** nodes with A* one would set the function which estimates the costs to the target node to zero (since there is no target node). Setting the function which estimates the costs to the target node to zero makes A* identical with Dijkstra; Dijkstra is a special case of A*. (It's questionable if one should call the algorithm still "A*" (and not simply "Dijkstra") if the function is set to zero, because having a non-zero function is the core of A*.)
- When we try to find the shortest path to all nodes, we could also say: Dijkstra is sufficient. The refinement of A* is not necessary and doesn't help us here.
- The last remark is also true for searching in a graph, for instance: Find the node marked with a specific flag which is closest to a given source node. Since you don't know the target in advance it's not possible to define a function which estimates the costs to the searched node, thus A* (in the narrower sense of a non-zero function) is not applicable.

Comment: I don't think you are right about Dijkstra being better at finding all nodes.  You can simply omit the early check for the goal node in A* and it would do the same thing as Dijkstra.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added a few remarks to my answer. But I am still unhappy with it. I should never have answered.