# Can Astar visit nodes more than once?

Tags: a-star

I've been reading wikipedia's Astar [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). In their implementaion, they check each node if it's in the `closed` set, and if so they skip it. Isn't it possible, that if the heuristic is admissible but **NOT** consistent, that we might need to revisit a node twice (or more) in order to improve it's `f` value?
This is the relevant code

```
for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
    if neighbor in closedset //This if condition bothers me
        continue
    tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)
    if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor] 
        came_from[neighbor] := current 
        g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
        f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
        if neighbor not in openset
            add neighbor to openset
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is below the psuedocode on the linked page, and also in the Description section on that page.  From the remark below the psuedo code:

> Remark: the above pseudocode assumes that the heuristic function is
>   monotonic (or consistent, see below), which is a frequent case in many
>   practical problems, such as the Shortest Distance Path in road
>   networks. However, if the assumption is not true, nodes in the closed
>   set may be rediscovered and their cost improved. In other words, the
>   closed set can be omitted (yielding a tree search algorithm) if a
>   solution is guaranteed to exist, or if the algorithm is adapted so
>   that new nodes are added to the open set only if they have a lower f
>   value than at any previous iteration.

So yes, the pseudocode does assume the heuristic is consistent and would have to be modified if it was not.