# Is it possible to find a optimal heuristic for this graph search example?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, a-star, heuristics

If we have a problem like the one in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjUl6.gif). 
We are in Arad, for example, and we want to go to Fagaras using a informed search algorithm (like A*) and the only information available is the one in the picture, is it possible to get a heuristics that is not trivial, but consistent and admissible?

Comment: I don't understand your question completely but I assume that you are asking for shortest path problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem And also take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yes! But is it possible to use a* algorithm and explore less nodes than dijkstra?

Comment: Then this is a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332478/2104879

Comment: No, I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain well the question. Finding an admissible heuristic for the mario problem is easier because you know the distance to the goal without obstacles, an ideal case. Here, you don't have a procedure for finding heuristic(node) without doing other search problem.

Comment: As far as I know Dijkstra and A* et al only work on grid path problems. Your linked image needs something else entirely (look for _Route Inspection problem_ or _Rural postman problem_). If the nodes aren't positioned decently (direction + distance is a decent indicator), you'll just have to brute force it.

Comment: No, Dijkstra's algorithm and A* are both designed to work on graph problems like this one. This issue is that A* tries to leverage information above and beyond the edge weights to solve the problem faster. You're saying you don't have any information above and beyond the edge weights, so A* isn't going to help.