# Is Dijkstra's a special case for A*?

Tags: dijkstra, a-star

According to a.o. [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332466/how-does-dijkstras-algorithm-and-a-star-compare/1332478#1332478), [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) is a special case of the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

> [**Special case**](https://www.definitions.net/definition/special%20case)
>
> In logic, especially as applied in mathematics, concept A is a special case or specialization of concept B precisely if every
>   instance of A is also an instance of B but not vice versa, or
>   equivalently, if B is a generalization of A.

There are, however, cases that produce different results for A* with a constant zero heuristic when compared to Dijktra's algorithm.

One of these is their behaviour when the graph contains negative cycles: while A*'s [closed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) handling completely avoids such cycles, Dijkstra's follows negative cycles infinite times before proceeding.

Another edge case where their results may differ, this time even with an [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), is when A* **underestimates** the cost of the final edge in a graph. Given a graph like this:
[image: graph with nodes A, B, C, D]

Most A* implementations, including the psuedo-code example at wikipedia, would incorrectly assume A-B-D to be the shortest path if the heuristic function for rates B to D below 2, while Dijkstra correctly yields A-C-D.

Can Dijkstra's algorithm still be viewed as special case for A*, given the above?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by »*A\*'s closed set handling*«. If there is a negative cycle (or even just any negative weight) and you are using the heuristic »*h(e)=0 for all edges e*« then *h* is not admissible and A\* won't compute optimal paths. Maybe Dijkstra's algorithm is a specialization of A\* *with an admissible heuristic* but certainly not a specialization of A\* *with an inadmissible heuristic*.

Comment: Heh, I hadn't even considered the admissibility! Good point (you could convert it into an answer, I'd argue). With closed set handling I refer to the fact that A* will skip any node it had already visited, thus avoiding loops.

Comment: Updated the question with a differing result using an admissible heuristic.

Comment: @Stratadox In the graph above, A* with the heuristic »*h(e)=0 for all edges e*« yields the same result with Dijkstra's, i.e. A-C-D. It does not assume A-B-D to be the shortest path.

Comment: @Gorisanson can you demonstrate this? The pseudocode on the wikipedia article would consider B as first option (cost 2 vs 4) and schedule D as next option with a priority of 2 (cost of B + h(D) = 2), run the next iteration and find that D == goal: path detected. If I'm mistaken, please correct me, but this explanation fits my unit test results.

Comment: @Stratadox Let me explain the procedure of A* algorithm with the heuristic *»h(e)=0 for all edges e«* for the graph. The pseudocode on the wikipedia article would consider A as first option and calculate `fScore` for B (cost 2) and C (cost 4). And it consider B as next option (B: cost 2 vs C: cost 4) and calculate `fScore` for D (cost 12). And now, it consider C as next option (C: cost 4 vs D: cost 12) and calculate `fScore` for D (cost 8). And it consider D as next option and if finds that D is the goal: path detected. So it finds A-C-D as the shortest path with cost 8.